# Python: return a list of the index() of objects filtered from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, filtering

I am using the following function to filter out many file types from a database query. The file extensions had variations of capitalization (e.g., Tif, tIF, TIF, tif). However, I need to query further with capitalization as-is in the system.

My solution:

1. Make a copy of the dataframe (Pandas) lowercase **(already done)**.
2. Perform the filter based on two lists **(already done)**.
3. Return a list of the index (indices?) of where the filtered objects were prior to being filtered.
4. Remove the objects from my original list with the list of indices. Which keeps my capitalization and removes the correct items.

I can't figure out how to return the original indices. Please help!
variables:
`path_list_lowercase`
`suffixes_unwanted`

```
def index_pos_filtered_paths(path_list_lowercase, suffixes_unwanted):
        for [x for x in path_list_lowercase if all(y not in x for y in suffixes_unwanted)]
        return path_list_lowercase(x).index(suffixes_unwanted(y))


index_of_filtered_paths_list = index_pos_filtered_paths(path_list_lowercase, suffixes_unwanted)
```

[image: Screenshot. Same as above. Just easier to visualize with the colored variables]

Comment: [how to ask good pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerate function to get the index

```
[{'value':x, 'index':i} for i,x in enumerate(path_list_lowercase)]
```

Comment: Yes, but how will I know what indices were filtered? Once the filter is done, the index is reassigned. It's thousands of files, so I'm hoping for an easy way to simply return a list.